# error trying to run BehaviorSpace experiments from bash

Tags: java, xml, bash, netlogo

I am running my model in NetLogo and it works fine. A strange thing happens when I try to run some experiments defined in an xml file and launched with this script:

```
java -Xmx4096m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp /Applications/NetLogo\ 5.3/Java/netlogo-mac-app.jar org.nlogo.headless.Main --model mymodel.nlogo --setup-file experiments-.25-times-per-day.xml


Exception in thread "main" Expected a constant. at position 0 in 
at org.nlogo.compiler.CompilerExceptionThrowers$.exception(CompilerExceptionThrowers.scala:26)
at org.nlogo.compiler.ConstantParser.readConstantPrefix(ConstantParser.scala:115)
at org.nlogo.compiler.ConstantParser.getConstantValue(ConstantParser.scala:66)
at org.nlogo.compiler.Compiler$$anonfun$readFromString$1.apply(Compiler.scala:92)
at scala.Either$RightProjection.getOrElse(Either.scala:479)
at org.nlogo.compiler.Compiler$.readFromString(Compiler.scala:91)
at org.nlogo.nvm.DefaultCompilerServices.readFromString(DefaultCompilerServices.scala:25)
at org.nlogo.lab.ProtocolLoader$Loader$$anonfun$readEnumeratedValueSetElement$1$1.apply(ProtocolLoader.scala:84)
at org.nlogo.lab.ProtocolLoader$Loader$$anonfun$readEnumeratedValueSetElement$1$1.apply(ProtocolLoader.scala:83)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:233)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:233)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:76)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:76)
at org.nlogo.lab.ProtocolLoader$Loader.readEnumeratedValueSetElement$1(ProtocolLoader.scala:83)
at org.nlogo.lab.ProtocolLoader$Loader$$anonfun$valueSets$1$1.apply(ProtocolLoader.scala:88)
at org.nlogo.lab.ProtocolLoader$Loader$$anonfun$valueSets$1$1.apply(ProtocolLoader.scala:85)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:239)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:239)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:76)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:239)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:76)
at org.nlogo.lab.ProtocolLoader$Loader.valueSets$1(ProtocolLoader.scala:85)
at org.nlogo.lab.ProtocolLoader$Loader.readProtocolElement(ProtocolLoader.scala:102)
at org.nlogo.lab.ProtocolLoader$Loader$$anonfun$load$1.apply(ProtocolLoader.scala:63)
at org.nlogo.lab.ProtocolLoader$Loader$$anonfun$load$1.apply(ProtocolLoader.scala:63)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:233)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:233)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:76)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:76)
at org.nlogo.lab.ProtocolLoader$Loader.load(ProtocolLoader.scala:63)
at org.nlogo.lab.ProtocolLoader.loadOne(ProtocolLoader.scala:17)
at org.nlogo.lab.Lab.newWorker(Lab.scala:27)
at org.nlogo.lab.Lab.run(Lab.scala:42)
at org.nlogo.headless.Main$.runExperiment(Main.scala:24)
at org.nlogo.headless.Main$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Main.scala:14)
at org.nlogo.headless.Main$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Main.scala:14)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:197)
at org.nlogo.headless.Main$.main(Main.scala:14)
at org.nlogo.headless.Main.main(Main.scala)
```

I don't understand where to look at from the error message, since it is not pointing any specific part of the model - as far as I can see...

this is an excerpt from my setup file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE experiments SYSTEM "behaviorspace.dtd">
<experiments>
 <experiment name="india-hagerstrand-one-at-random" repetitions="100" runMetricsEveryStep="false">
    <setup>setup</setup>
    <go>go</go>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="dataset">
        <value value="&quot;india&quot;"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="schedule">
        <value value="&quot;one at random&quot;"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="logic">
        <value value="&quot;hagerstrand&quot;"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="debug?">
        <value value="false"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="ticks-in-semester">
        <value value="45"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="experiment">
        <value value="experiment-.25"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
</experiment>
</experiments>
```

the error happens only if I load the experiment from the xml file, otherwise it works. I have validated my xml against the behaviorspace.dtd and it appears to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

the error was caused by the xml code, specifically one line was wrong, when encapsulating a string:

```
<enumeratedValueSet variable="experiment">
    <value value="&quot;experiments-4&quot;"/>
</enumeratedValueSet>
```